# How do I reload my plugin only and update values ingame

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

**DISCLAIMER:** please do be patient, as I am a new young developer and I have seen how people get upset/angry if someone does not know how to format a question correctly.

So I have this command that is supposed to basically restart **JUST** my plugin and config.yml:

```
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hellopluginreload") || command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hpr"))

    this.getPluginLoader().disablePlugin(this);
    this.getPluginLoader().enablePlugin(this);
    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7[&dHi&bMessage&7]  &aSuccessfully &cReloaded &dHi&bMessage"));
    return true;
```

without having to restart the whole server, because of course, that is an inconvenience to fellow plugin users. I have a launchpad (playerMoveListener) class:

```
import me.yarkosharko.helloplugin.Commands.bounceCommand;
import me.yarkosharko.helloplugin.HelloPlugin;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;

public class playerMoveListener implements Listener {

        HelloPlugin plugin;

    public playerMoveListener(HelloPlugin plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;


        }

    @EventHandler
        public void onPlayerWalk(PlayerMoveEvent me){
        if (plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("enabled")) {
            Player p = me.getPlayer();
            Location underBlock = p.getLocation();
            underBlock.setY(underBlock.getY() -1);
            if (p.getLocation().getBlock().getType().equals(Material.valueOf(plugin.getConfig().getString("top-block"))) && underBlock.getBlock().getType().equals(Material.valueOf(plugin.getConfig().getString("bottom-block")))){
                p.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(2).setY(1));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

that bounces people up when they touch a certain block. The problem is when I put a new block in the config.yml, and run the command /hellopluginreload it updates the config.yml, but in game, the newly added block never works as a launchpad, and only the old block works.
Just to clarify, yes I am using correct block names, as when I restart my server it works
Again, How do I reload my plugin only and update values ingame (preferably with the /hellopluginreload command), without using /reload or /stop ect.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dependency like https://github.com/Simplix-Softworks/SimplixStorage
for files.

With that you can put `Config c = new Config("config.yml", plugin.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath());` under `HelloPlugin plugin;` and `c.forceReload()` on the first line of the onPlayerWalk function.

Hope that helps!